# how to use Double Tap event in android canvas to save current Image

Tags: java, android

**I have Class which Extends View I'm able To  Move one Image Over another For This I use Two Bitmap Image one Over Another now i want to save image's using Double Tap event but i dnt know how to do this....can anyone have some idea or code for this ......**

`public class ShowCanvas extends View {

```
Bitmap CanvasBitmap;
Bitmap ScaledBitmap;
Bitmap smallbitmap;
private static final int INVALID_POINTER_ID = -1;

private Drawable mImage;
private float mPosX;
private float mPosY;

private float mLastTouchX;
private float mLastTouchY;
private int mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;

private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;
private float mScaleFactor = 1.f;

public ShowCanvas(Context context) {
```

this(context, null, 0);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

```
    ScaledBitmap = DrawView.scaled;

    mImage = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), Dress.bitmap);


    System.out.println("MImage" +mImage);

    mImage.setBounds(0, 0, mImage.getIntrinsicWidth(),
            mImage.getIntrinsicHeight());

}

public ShowCanvas(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public ShowCanvas(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
}

public void setBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    CanvasBitmap = bitmap;

    System.out.println("CanvasBitmap" + CanvasBitmap);

    int X = CanvasBitmap.getHeight();
    int Y = CanvasBitmap.getWidth();

    System.out.println("CanvasBitmap " + X + "\t" + Y);

}

@Override
public boolean isLongClickable() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    System.out.println("ISLongClickable");
    return super.isLongClickable();
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    // Let the ScaleGestureDetector inspect all events.
    mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);




    final int action = ev.getAction();

    switch (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
        final float x = ev.getX();
        final float y = ev.getY();

        mLastTouchX = x;
        mLastTouchY = y;
        mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(0);


        break;
    }

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
        final int pointerIndex = ev.findPointerIndex(mActivePointerId);
        final float x = ev.getX(pointerIndex);
        final float y = ev.getY(pointerIndex);

        // Only move if the ScaleGestureDetector isn't processing a
        // gesture.
        if (!mScaleDetector.isInProgress()) {
            final float dx = x - mLastTouchX;
            final float dy = y - mLastTouchY;

            mPosX += dx;
            mPosY += dy;

            invalidate();
        }

        mLastTouchX = x;
        mLastTouchY = y;

        break;
    }

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
        mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
        break;
    }

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
        mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
        break;
    }

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: {
        final int pointerIndex = (ev.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK) >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT;
        final int pointerId = ev.getPointerId(pointerIndex);
        if (pointerId == mActivePointerId) {
            // This was our active pointer going up. Choose a new
            // active pointer and adjust accordingly.
            final int newPointerIndex = pointerIndex == 0 ? 1 : 0;
            mLastTouchX = ev.getX(newPointerIndex);
            mLastTouchY = ev.getY(newPointerIndex);
            mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(newPointerIndex);
        }
        break;
    }
    }

    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Paint mpaint = new Paint();

    canvas.save();
    canvas.drawBitmap(ScaledBitmap, 0, 0, mpaint);
    Log.d("DEBUG", "X: " + mPosX + " Y: " + mPosY);
    canvas.translate(mPosX, mPosY);
    canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);
    mImage.draw(canvas);


    canvas.restore();

}

private class ScaleListener extends
        ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();

        // Don't let the object get too small or too large.
        mScaleFactor = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 10.0f));

        invalidate();
        return true;
    }
}
```

}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean double tap you have to use GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener. check this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener.html)

try this

```
public class MyView extends View {

GestureDetector gestureDetector;

public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
            // creating new gesture detector
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureListener());
}

// skipping measure calculation and drawing

    // delegate the event to the gesture detector
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
    return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e);
}


private class GestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return true;
    }
    // event when double tap occurs
    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
        float x = e.getX();
        float y = e.getY();

        Log.d("Double Tap", "Tapped at: (" + x + "," + y + ")");

        return true;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Sorry I use This but it didnt works .. also i dnt know exactly where to use this...

Comment: Better is  using a Long Press.Or are you using that already for something else? The advantages over a long touch over a double touch:

Long Press is a recommeded interaction in the UI Guidelines, double touch is not.
It's what users expect; a user might not find a double touch action as they won't go looking for it
It's already handled in the API.
Implementing Double Touch will affect handling of single touches, because you'll have to wait to see if every single touch turns into a double touch before you can process it.